# Why is jsonwebtoken throwing an "invalid signature" error?

Tags: node.js, jwt, express-jwt

I am using the jsonwebtoken package (https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) to handle JWTs in my project.  No matter what I try, it gives me this error: `name: 'JsonWebTokenError', message: 'invalid signature'`

Here is where I sign the JWT:

```
const addBearerToken = (myUser, cb) => {
  jwt.sign({user: myUser, userId: myUser.id}, 'helloworld', (err, token) => {
    if (err) return (err, null)
    userRepo.update(myUser._id, {authToken: token}, (err, myUser) => {
      if (err) {
        return cb(err, null)
      } else {
        return cb(null, token)
      }
    })
  })
}
```

And here is where I try to verify it:

```
const checkForJWT = (req, res, next) => {
  let bearerHeader = req.header('Authorization').split(' ')
  let token = bearerHeader[1]
  console.log(token + '  ||  token')
  jwt.verify(token, 'helloworld', (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      return (err, null) // this is where the error is thrown
    } else {
    ...
    }
  })
}
```

I'm using 'helloworld' as a stand in for my secret key.  I suspect the problem is with the secret key but like i said, I'm not sure what is going on behind the scenes that is causing this error.

If I use jwt.decode(token, 'helloworld') I get all the right information back.  But I get the error when i use jwt.verify().

Any help is much appreciated.  Let me know if you need any more information from my code.

Comment: well, you're adding your whole user record to the token (bad enough), and that record even contains a token that you stored into your db before (even worse). I suggest to add only a few necessary claims, e.g. the user id and an expiration time to the token. You can insprect your token at https://jwt.io

Comment: Okay, I'll check out jwt.io.  I forgot to add that jwt.decode() works just fine, but jwt.verify() does not, which seems strange to me.

Comment: I just used jwt.io and it verified the signature.  I've also changed the token above to remove the user info.

Comment: The result is the same as before. the debugger says it works, but in my program, I get an error.

Comment: I don't think jwt.io really verified the old token. If you add the secret on the right after pasting the token on the left, it calculates a new signature which is automatically verified. Edit your question and add the changed code and current token after your last modifications.

Comment: Yes, you are correct; I was mistaken about it being verified.   I will post the new code and token in a bit.  I'm having trouble removing all of the user information, which I would rather not have available on SO.  Thanks for the help, by the way.

Comment: you're welcome. Pls. never post real data, only test data here. You can flag your post "in need of moderator intervention" and explain the problem. I think they can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a base64 text as a key. I was also facing this very problem but using base64 key solved my problem.

Comment: You could explain in detail how precisely to utilize base64 to solve OP's question/problem.  I am a reviewer.  StackOverflow requested review because you are a new contributor.  Your answer is appreciated & helpful.  This comment is intended to help you make a good answer into an excellent one.

Comment: jwt.verify takes a secret or public key as the second argument to validate the signature. The key should be in base64 format (ending with ==). This solved my problem of invalid signature

Comment: If you have fully solved your OP's question/problem, then you should write up an answer for it, then accept your answer so that people browsing (perhaps years from now) can easily see the question-answer without needing to read through all the comments.

Comment: a) it's neither clear what problem you really had nor how base64 encoding solved it and I doubt it would have helped the OP. b) a base64 encoded string can have 0, 1 or 2 padding characters (=). It's a common misconception that a base64 string always ends with ==